# Python Tkinter Tic-Tac-Toe window won't be created when function is called

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a tic-tac-toe on python tkinter using a canvas as a school homework and for a restart button I found 2 solutions:

1) reseting all variables and the canvas.

2) opening a new window and closing the previous one but can't track the wins.

I currently choosed the 2) because I though it would be easier to make since I'm new to python and tkinter. And when I tried to reset the canvas, I wanted to simply draw a big white square all over it and draw back the lines of the grid but it simply bugged when I started it and gave me: `can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed`.

When I searched how to do that, it seems i had to do the main function (creating the window and canvas and buttons) and call it at the beginning of the program then use `.destroy()` and `main()` in the function restart. I found it on this post who didn't had a restart issue: [Tic-tac-toe using python tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54979853/tic-tac-toe-using-python-tkinter)

The problem is... when I start the program... The window won't even pop. I did typed main() at the very end but either I did something stupid, or what I coded simply didn't work.

Here's the code, and sorry for the french words all across the code, it's because I'm french obviously :)
 :

```
## Importation des Modules ##
from tkinter import *

## Création de la fenêtre / creating the sheet ##
def main():
    fen = Tk()
    fen.title('Game')
    texte=Label(fen, text="Go ahead Mr Joestar")
    texte.grid(row=0, column=0)
    pos=Label(fen, text='(Nope;Nope)')
    pos.grid(row=0, column=1)

##Canvas##
    dessin=Canvas(fen, bg="white", width=301, height=301) #canvas
    dessin.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx=2, pady=2, columnspan=2) #Position Canvas

    dessin.create_line(99, 0, 99, 301, width=1, fill='black')
    dessin.create_line(201, 0, 201, 301, width=1, fill='black')
    dessin.create_line(0, 99, 301, 99, width=1, fill='black')
    dessin.create_line(0, 201, 301, 201, width=1, fill='black')
##buttons##
    bouton_quitter = Button(fen, text='Quitter', command=fen.destroy) #Quitter
    bouton_quitter.grid(row=2, column=0)

    bouton_restart = Button(fen, text='Recommencer', command=restart(fen)) #Restart
    bouton_restart.grid(row=2, column=1)
##binds##
    dessin.bind("<Motion>", Position) #event motion mouse
    dessin.bind("<Button-1>", cases) #event mouse 1

##Liste / list ###
list=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
print(list)
##Variables##
Joueur=1 #Joueur1 (nommé Joestar) = 1 ; Joueur2 (nommé DArbi) = -1 / player1=1 ; player2=-1
V1=0#condition victoire j1 / Winning condition for player 1
V2=0#condition victoire j2 / Winning condition for player 2
IDC=0 #identifier la case / for identifying which cell
turns=0#nombre de tours

##Function position##
def Position(event):
    pos.configure(text='('+str(event.x)+'.'+str(event.y)+')')

##Fuction win##
def win(list, V1, V2): #pour voir qui a gagné / to see who won
    if list[0][0]+list[0][1]+list[0][2]==3: #Vérification lignes
        V1=1
    elif list[0][0]+list[0][1]+list[0][2]==-3:
        V2=1
    if list[1][0]+list[1][1]+list[1][2]==3:
        V1=1
    elif list[1][0]+list[1][1]+list[1][2]==-3:
        V2=1
    if list[2][0]+list[2][1]+list[2][2]==3:
        V1=1
    elif list[2][0]+list[2][1]+list[2][2]==-3:
        V2=1
    if list[0][0]+list[1][0]+list[2][0]==3: #Vérification colones
        V1=1
    elif list[0][0]+list[1][0]+list[2][0]==-3:
        V2=1
    if list[0][1]+list[1][1]+list[2][1]==3:
        V1=1
    elif list[0][1]+list[1][1]+list[2][1]==-3:
        V2=1
    if list[0][0]+list[1][1]+list[2][2]==3:#Diagonales
        V1=1
    elif list[0][0]+list[1][1]+list[2][2]==-3:
        V2=1
    if list[0][2]+list[1][1]+list[2][0]==3:
        V1=1
    elif list[0][2]+list[1][1]+list[2][0]==-3:
        V2=1
    if V1==1 and V2==0:
        texte.configure(text='Joestar win !')
    elif V1==0 and V2==1:
        texte.configure(text='DArbi win')
    elif turns==9 and V1==0 and V2==0 or V1==1 and V2==1:
        texte.configure(text='No one won...')

##Function remplir##
def remplir(list,IDC):#pour remplir les cases
    global Joueur #to edit Joueur for all the program
    if IDC ==1:#Cell 1
        if list[0][0]==0:
            list[0][0]=Joueur
            if list[0][0]==1:
                dessin.create_line(10,10,90,90, width=1) #cell 1 cross
                dessin.create_line(10, 90, 90, 10, width=1)
            elif list[0][0]==-1:
                dessin.create_oval(10, 10, 90, 90, width=1)#cell 1 circle
            Joueur=(-Joueur)#nextplayer
        elif list[0][0]!=0:
            print("case déjà prise")
    if IDC ==2:#Cell 2
        if list[0][1]==0:
            list[0][1]=Joueur
            if list[0][1]==1:
                dessin.create_line(110,10,190,90, width=1)
                dessin.create_line(110,90,190,10, width=1)
            elif list[0][1]==-1:
                dessin.create_oval(110, 10, 190, 90, width=1)
            Joueur=(-Joueur)
        elif list[0][1]!=0:
            print("case déjà prise")
    if IDC ==3:#Cell 3
        if list[0][2]==0:
            list[0][2]=Joueur
            if list[0][2]==1:
                dessin.create_line(210,10,290,90, width=1)
                dessin.create_line(210,90,290,10, width=1)
            elif list[0][2]==-1:
                dessin.create_oval(210, 10, 290, 90, width=1)
            Joueur=(-Joueur)
        elif list[0][2]!=0:
            print("case déjà prise")
    if IDC ==4: #Cell 4
        if list[1][0]==0:
            list[1][0]=Joueur
            if list[1][0]==1:
                dessin.create_line(10,110,90,190, width=1)
                dessin.create_line(10, 190, 90, 110, width=1)
            elif list[1][0]==-1:
                dessin.create_oval(10, 110, 90, 190, width=1)
            Joueur=(-Joueur)
        elif list[1][0]!=0:
            print("case déjà prise")
    if IDC ==5:#Cell 5
        if list[1][1]==0:
            list[1][1]=Joueur
            if list[1][1]==1:
                dessin.create_line(110,110,190,190, width=1)
                dessin.create_line(110,190,190,110, width=1)
            elif list[1][1]==-1:
                dessin.create_oval(110, 110, 190, 190, width=1)
            Joueur=(-Joueur)
        elif list[1][1]!=0:
            print("case déjà prise")
    if IDC ==6:#Cell 6
        if list[1][2]==0:
            list[1][2]=Joueur
            if list[1][2]==1:
                dessin.create_line(210,110,290,190, width=1)
                dessin.create_line(210,190,290,110, width=1)
            elif list[1][2]==-1:
                dessin.create_oval(210, 110, 290, 190, width=1)
            Joueur=(-Joueur)
        elif list[1][2]!=0:
            print("case déjà prise")
    if IDC ==7: #Cell 7
        if list[2][0]==0:
            list[2][0]=Joueur
            if list[2][0]==1:
                dessin.create_line(10,210,90,290, width=1)
                dessin.create_line(10, 290, 90, 210, width=1)
            elif list[2][0]==-1:
                dessin.create_oval(10, 210, 90, 290, width=1)
            Joueur=(-Joueur)
        elif list[2][0]!=0:
            print("case déjà prise")
    if IDC ==8:#Cell 8
        if list[2][1]==0:
            list[2][1]=Joueur
            if list[2][1]==1:
                dessin.create_line(110,210,190,290, width=1)
                dessin.create_line(110,290,190,210, width=1)
            elif list[2][1]==-1:
                dessin.create_oval(110, 210, 190, 290, width=1)
            Joueur=(-Joueur)
        elif list[2][1]!=0:
            print("case déjà prise")
    if IDC ==9:#Cell 9
        if list[2][2]==0:
            list[2][2]=Joueur
            if list[2][2]==1:
                dessin.create_line(210,210,290,290, width=1)
                dessin.create_line(210,290,290,210, width=1)
            elif list[2][2]==-1:
                dessin.create_oval(210, 210, 290, 290, width=1)
            Joueur=(-Joueur)
        elif list[2][2]!=0:
            print("case déjà prise")

##Fuction cases##
def cases(event):
    if int(event.x)>2 and int(event.x)<100 and int(event.y)>0 and int(event.y)<100: #CASE A1
        print('A1')
        IDC=1
        remplir(list,IDC)
        win(list, V1, V2)
    elif int(event.x)>102 and int(event.x)<200 and int(event.y)>0 and int(event.y)<100: #CASE A2
        print('A2')
        IDC=2
        remplir(list,IDC)
        win(list, V1, V2)
    elif int(event.x)>202 and int(event.x)<300 and int(event.y)>0 and int(event.y)<100: #CASE A3
        print('A3')
        IDC=3
        remplir(list,IDC)
        win(list, V1, V2)
    elif int(event.x)>2 and int(event.x)<100 and int(event.y)>100 and int(event.y)<200: #CASE B1
        print('B1')
        IDC=4
        remplir(list,IDC)
        win(list, V1, V2)
    elif int(event.x)>100 and int(event.x)<200 and int(event.y)>102 and int(event.y)<200: #CASE B2
        print('B2')
        IDC=5
        remplir(list,IDC)
        win(list, V1, V2)
    elif int(event.x)>202 and int(event.x)<300 and int(event.y)>102 and int(event.y)<200: #CASE B3
        print('B3')
        IDC=6
        remplir(list,IDC)
        win(list, V1, V2)
    elif int(event.x)>2 and int(event.x)<100 and int(event.y)>202 and int(event.y)<300: #CASE C1
        print('C1')
        IDC=7
        remplir(list,IDC)
        win(list, V1, V2)
    elif int(event.x)>100 and int(event.x)<200 and int(event.y)>202 and int(event.y)<300: #CASE C2
        print('C2')
        IDC=8
        remplir(list,IDC)
        win(list, V1, V2)
    elif int(event.x)>202 and int(event.x)<300 and int(event.y)>202 and int(event.y)<300: #CASE C3
        print('C3')
        IDC=9
        remplir(list,IDC)
        win(list, V1, V2)
    else:
        print('no')

##Fuctions:others##
def restart(fen):
    fen.destroy()
    main()


##Mainloop##
main()
```

Please, point out everything you find wrong or weird you find.

Thank you for your time !

Edit1: Furas pointed out one thing that fixed my problem: the () in the button(command=restart()). they were what prevented my restart button from working with whatever was in the restart function. Thanks Furas !

Thank you for also finding a way to make the code more clean and compact. But im going to change what i coded and since im not that good at coding, i think the method i used is more safe.

I'll remove the whole "main" function and make it so the reset button reset the variables and canvas.

Thank you again anyway.

Edit2: maybe i should just delete that post now since the real problem was about reseting the whole game and i found out it was a problem in the restart button(command=).

Comment: `command=` needs function name without `()`. If you have to assign function with arguments then you can use `lambda` to create function without arguments - `command=lambda:restart(fen)`

Comment: to show window you have to run `fen.mainloop()`. It runs loop which works all time (until you close/destroy window) and it gets key/mouse events from system, sends them to widgets and (re)draw window when it is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few problems

1. you have to use

   ```
   fen.mainloop()
   ```

   to start loop which gets key/mouse events from system, sends them to widgets and (re)draw window when it is needed
2. `command=` needs function's name without `()`. If you have to assign function with arguments then you can use `lambda` to create function whithout arguments

   ```
   command=lambda:restart(fen)
   ```
3. inside `main()` you have to use `global` for `pos`, `dessin`, `texte` to have access to these variables in other functions

   ```
   def main():
       global pos
       global dessin
       global texte
   ```
4. you have to reset `list` when you restart game

   ```
   def restart(fen):
       global list

       list = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
   ```

   Probably you may have to do the same with other variables but I didn't test it.

---

**BTW:** when you create object on canvas then you get its ID so you can later access it

```
items_id = dessin.create_line(...)

items_id = dessin.create_oval(...)
```

You could keep IDs on list and late you can use IDs to remove items from canvas and you don't have to `destroy` window.

But in both situations you have to reset all other values.

---

**BTW:** in `remplir` you could convert `IDC` to `row, column`

```
row = (IDC-1) // 3
column = (IDC-1) % 3
```

and then you could use `list[row][column]` and `create_line(column*100+10, row*100+10, column*100+90, row*100+90, ...)` - you would no have to write the same code 9 times.

---

```
## Importation des Modules ##
from tkinter import *

## Création de la fenêtre / creating the sheet ##
def main():
    global pos
    global dessin
    global texte

    fen = Tk()
    fen.title('Game')
    texte=Label(fen, text="Go ahead Mr Joestar")
    texte.grid(row=0, column=0)
    pos=Label(fen, text='(Nope;Nope)')
    pos.grid(row=0, column=1)

##Canvas##
    dessin=Canvas(fen, bg="white", width=301, height=301) #canvas
    dessin.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx=2, pady=2, columnspan=2) #Position Canvas

    dessin.create_line(99, 0, 99, 301, width=1, fill='black')
    dessin.create_line(201, 0, 201, 301, width=1, fill='black')
    dessin.create_line(0, 99, 301, 99, width=1, fill='black')
    dessin.create_line(0, 201, 301, 201, width=1, fill='black')
##buttons##
    bouton_quitter = Button(fen, text='Quitter', command=fen.destroy) #Quitter
    bouton_quitter.grid(row=2, column=0)

    bouton_restart = Button(fen, text='Recommencer', command=lambda:restart(fen)) #Restart
    bouton_restart.grid(row=2, column=1)
##binds##
    dessin.bind("<Motion>", Position) #event motion mouse
    dessin.bind("<Button-1>", cases) #event mouse 1
    fen.mainloop()

##Liste / list ###
list=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
print(list)
##Variables##
Joueur=1 #Joueur1 (nommé Joestar) = 1 ; Joueur2 (nommé DArbi) = -1 / player1=1 ; player2=-1
V1=0#condition victoire j1 / Winning condition for player 1
V2=0#condition victoire j2 / Winning condition for player 2
IDC=0 #identifier la case / for identifying which cell
turns=0#nombre de tours

##Function position##
def Position(event):
    pos.configure(text='('+str(event.x)+'.'+str(event.y)+')')

##Fuction win##
def win(list, V1, V2): #pour voir qui a gagné / to see who won
    if list[0][0]+list[0][1]+list[0][2]==3: #Vérification lignes
        V1=1
    elif list[0][0]+list[0][1]+list[0][2]==-3:
        V2=1
    if list[1][0]+list[1][1]+list[1][2]==3:
        V1=1
    elif list[1][0]+list[1][1]+list[1][2]==-3:
        V2=1
    if list[2][0]+list[2][1]+list[2][2]==3:
        V1=1
    elif list[2][0]+list[2][1]+list[2][2]==-3:
        V2=1
    if list[0][0]+list[1][0]+list[2][0]==3: #Vérification colones
        V1=1
    elif list[0][0]+list[1][0]+list[2][0]==-3:
        V2=1
    if list[0][1]+list[1][1]+list[2][1]==3:
        V1=1
    elif list[0][1]+list[1][1]+list[2][1]==-3:
        V2=1
    if list[0][0]+list[1][1]+list[2][2]==3:#Diagonales
        V1=1
    elif list[0][0]+list[1][1]+list[2][2]==-3:
        V2=1
    if list[0][2]+list[1][1]+list[2][0]==3:
        V1=1
    elif list[0][2]+list[1][1]+list[2][0]==-3:
        V2=1
    if V1==1 and V2==0:
        texte.configure(text='Joestar win !')
    elif V1==0 and V2==1:
        texte.configure(text='DArbi win')
    elif turns==9 and V1==0 and V2==0 or V1==1 and V2==1:
        texte.configure(text='No one won...')

##Function remplir##
def remplir(list,IDC):#pour remplir les cases
    global Joueur #to edit Joueur for all the program
    if IDC ==1:#Cell 1
        if list[0][0]==0:
            list[0][0]=Joueur
            if list[0][0]==1:
                dessin.create_line(10,10,90,90, width=1) #cell 1 cross
                dessin.create_line(10, 90, 90, 10, width=1)
            elif list[0][0]==-1:
                dessin.create_oval(10, 10, 90, 90, width=1)#cell 1 circle
            Joueur=(-Joueur)#nextplayer
        elif list[0][0]!=0:
            print("case déjà prise")
    if IDC ==2:#Cell 2
        if list[0][1]==0:
            list[0][1]=Joueur
            if list[0][1]==1:
                dessin.create_line(110,10,190,90, width=1)
                dessin.create_line(110,90,190,10, width=1)
            elif list[0][1]==-1:
                dessin.create_oval(110, 10, 190, 90, width=1)
            Joueur=(-Joueur)
        elif list[0][1]!=0:
            print("case déjà prise")
    if IDC ==3:#Cell 3
        if list[0][2]==0:
            list[0][2]=Joueur
            if list[0][2]==1:
                dessin.create_line(210,10,290,90, width=1)
                dessin.create_line(210,90,290,10, width=1)
            elif list[0][2]==-1:
                dessin.create_oval(210, 10, 290, 90, width=1)
            Joueur=(-Joueur)
        elif list[0][2]!=0:
            print("case déjà prise")
    if IDC ==4: #Cell 4
        if list[1][0]==0:
            list[1][0]=Joueur
            if list[1][0]==1:
                dessin.create_line(10,110,90,190, width=1)
                dessin.create_line(10, 190, 90, 110, width=1)
            elif list[1][0]==-1:
                dessin.create_oval(10, 110, 90, 190, width=1)
            Joueur=(-Joueur)
        elif list[1][0]!=0:
            print("case déjà prise")
    if IDC ==5:#Cell 5
        if list[1][1]==0:
            list[1][1]=Joueur
            if list[1][1]==1:
                dessin.create_line(110,110,190,190, width=1)
                dessin.create_line(110,190,190,110, width=1)
            elif list[1][1]==-1:
                dessin.create_oval(110, 110, 190, 190, width=1)
            Joueur=(-Joueur)
        elif list[1][1]!=0:
            print("case déjà prise")
    if IDC ==6:#Cell 6
        if list[1][2]==0:
            list[1][2]=Joueur
            if list[1][2]==1:
                dessin.create_line(210,110,290,190, width=1)
                dessin.create_line(210,190,290,110, width=1)
            elif list[1][2]==-1:
                dessin.create_oval(210, 110, 290, 190, width=1)
            Joueur=(-Joueur)
        elif list[1][2]!=0:
            print("case déjà prise")
    if IDC ==7: #Cell 7
        if list[2][0]==0:
            list[2][0]=Joueur
            if list[2][0]==1:
                dessin.create_line(10,210,90,290, width=1)
                dessin.create_line(10, 290, 90, 210, width=1)
            elif list[2][0]==-1:
                dessin.create_oval(10, 210, 90, 290, width=1)
            Joueur=(-Joueur)
        elif list[2][0]!=0:
            print("case déjà prise")
    if IDC ==8:#Cell 8
        if list[2][1]==0:
            list[2][1]=Joueur
            if list[2][1]==1:
                dessin.create_line(110,210,190,290, width=1)
                dessin.create_line(110,290,190,210, width=1)
            elif list[2][1]==-1:
                dessin.create_oval(110, 210, 190, 290, width=1)
            Joueur=(-Joueur)
        elif list[2][1]!=0:
            print("case déjà prise")
    if IDC ==9:#Cell 9
        if list[2][2]==0:
            list[2][2]=Joueur
            if list[2][2]==1:
                dessin.create_line(210,210,290,290, width=1)
                dessin.create_line(210,290,290,210, width=1)
            elif list[2][2]==-1:
                dessin.create_oval(210, 210, 290, 290, width=1)
            Joueur=(-Joueur)
        elif list[2][2]!=0:
            print("case déjà prise")

##Fuction cases##
def cases(event):
    if int(event.x)>2 and int(event.x)<100 and int(event.y)>0 and int(event.y)<100: #CASE A1
        print('A1')
        IDC=1
        remplir(list,IDC)
        win(list, V1, V2)
    elif int(event.x)>102 and int(event.x)<200 and int(event.y)>0 and int(event.y)<100: #CASE A2
        print('A2')
        IDC=2
        remplir(list,IDC)
        win(list, V1, V2)
    elif int(event.x)>202 and int(event.x)<300 and int(event.y)>0 and int(event.y)<100: #CASE A3
        print('A3')
        IDC=3
        remplir(list,IDC)
        win(list, V1, V2)
    elif int(event.x)>2 and int(event.x)<100 and int(event.y)>100 and int(event.y)<200: #CASE B1
        print('B1')
        IDC=4
        remplir(list,IDC)
        win(list, V1, V2)
    elif int(event.x)>100 and int(event.x)<200 and int(event.y)>102 and int(event.y)<200: #CASE B2
        print('B2')
        IDC=5
        remplir(list,IDC)
        win(list, V1, V2)
    elif int(event.x)>202 and int(event.x)<300 and int(event.y)>102 and int(event.y)<200: #CASE B3
        print('B3')
        IDC=6
        remplir(list,IDC)
        win(list, V1, V2)
    elif int(event.x)>2 and int(event.x)<100 and int(event.y)>202 and int(event.y)<300: #CASE C1
        print('C1')
        IDC=7
        remplir(list,IDC)
        win(list, V1, V2)
    elif int(event.x)>100 and int(event.x)<200 and int(event.y)>202 and int(event.y)<300: #CASE C2
        print('C2')
        IDC=8
        remplir(list,IDC)
        win(list, V1, V2)
    elif int(event.x)>202 and int(event.x)<300 and int(event.y)>202 and int(event.y)<300: #CASE C3
        print('C3')
        IDC=9
        remplir(list,IDC)
        win(list, V1, V2)
    else:
        print('no')

##Fuctions:others##
def restart(fen):
    global list

    fen.destroy()
    list=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
    main()


##Mainloop##
main()
```

Comment: I added information how to convert `IDC` to `row, column` and use it in `list[row][column]`

Answer (score 0):

Why destroying the previous canvas and making another one when you can simply do the **first solution** you though about.

The main problem here in my program was that the `bouton_restart = Button(fen, text='Recommencer', command=lambda:restart(fen)) #Restart`  had () in `command=restart()`. It should be `command=restart`.

Now I changed it and made it so that restart does `global [every variable and list at the start]` so that everything is changed back to how they were at the start. And I just cleaned the canvas by putting a rectangle filled white on the canvas and drawing the grid back. Which is **easier** to do as someone who's new to python and tkinter.

**Short version: 1) was the best one in this case; mistake in button(command=restart()).**